# Is there any risk in having reactive approach micro-services for API integration (direct using WebClient) ,without any message broker?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, reactive, messagebroker, spring-reactive, spring-reactor

I am implementing microservices API however not planning to have any message broker. API Services will talk to each other with WebClient/web flux.
Not using any message broker due to skill/budget challenges.
Is there any risk of going production like this? what are the drawbacks like failover/replay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on your requirements. A message broker is well suited to asynchronous, event driven applications. For request -response, I recommend http.  A message broker provides additional capabilities.  For instance, you get guaranteed delivery, partitioning, which is important if you require strict ordering, and a dead letter queue can be used to track and remediate failed requests. And as you mentioned, replay.